# Why can't I host my project on github pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a simple weather app using react I've built and pushed to Github. Everything works when I run it locally but when I try to host it on Github pages, I get a 404 error.

https://caseycling.github.io/weather-app/

I'm not sure what I did wrong as I took the same steps as with every other project I've succesfully deployed: went to settings and under Github pages, I chose master branch as the source. Initially, it was just displaying the readme but now it only displays a 404 error message. When I've googled this issue, some people are saying I need to move my folders to the root of the directory but I'm not sure how to do that exactly.

Here is the repo:

https://github.com/caseycling/weather-app/

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that in order to run a react app in github pages you need to setup the gh-pages plugin and have a special 'deploy' build script in package.json

https://itnext.io/so-you-want-to-host-your-single-age-react-app-on-github-pages-a826ab01e48
https://codeburst.io/deploy-react-to-github-pages-to-create-an-amazing-website-42d8b09cd4d
https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-deploy-your-react-application-to-github-pages-in-less-than-5-minutes-8c5f665a2d2a

There are also apparently certain restrictions in what you can do with the router in github pages websites, but for a simple app it should be sufficient.

Comment: What's more, make sure there's a `gh-pages`(default) branch.